# Displaying the same tiles when zoomed in instead of getting them from server

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display tiles on a map but when I zoom in too much the tiles disappear because the server doesn't have those tiles. I want to display the previously loaded tiles even if the user zooms in a lot.

Following is the code

```
    url_tile_provider = new UrlTileProvider(
                PathFinder.rainradar_HDBaseurl, uidList.get(0), db, TAG);

        tileoverlay_default = googleMap
                .addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(
                        url_tile_provider).visible(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are zooming too much than existing tiles get blur so it will try to get high resolution image. you can not restrict default map v2 but if you are using map like osmand that you have to change tiles loading logic and yo can restrict loading new tiles

Comment: You have some idea what king of logic i need to write any example or code snippet would be helpful

Comment: @user2197811 when zoom event called a service call made by app to fetch new tiles you can restrict that call after particular zoom level.

Comment: But how can i restrict and to display previous loaded tiles when no tiles coming from server